# How can I pass dynamic wait time using external file in Jmeter

Tags: dynamic, jmeter

I need to send request in Jmeter and have a pause (think time) between each iteration. I would like pass the time values through the CSV file. I have tried using constant time by providing variable and CSV file but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "not working"? You will not see the "sleep time" as by default JMeter doesn't include the time taken by [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) configured appropriately.

---

An example:

1. Given you have `sleep.csv` file with the following contents

   ```
   5000
   4000
   3000
   2000
   1000
   ```
2. A [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) configured to read this file

   [image]
3. A [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) configured to use the variable from the CSV Data Set Config

   [image]
4. A [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) configured to include pre/post processors and timers duration into the transaction

   [image]
5. You should see that the dynamic sleep times from the CSV file are getting applied in i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener:

   [image]

Comment: Both the solutions are working as expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSR223 Timer` with sleep, e.g. if variable is `sleepTime`

```
sleep(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("sleepTime")));
```